# How to calculate date using interval from table

Tags: mysql, date, intervals

I have a table with a `start_date`, `end_date` and an interval. I would like to update `end_date` with the value of `start_date` and the interval.

```
create table date_test (
    start_date      date,
    end_date        date,
    date_interval   varchar(45)
);
```

The values I am using for `date_interval` are like `- INTERVAL 1 WEEK`, `+ INTERVAL 1 MONTH`.

I would like to do something like:

```
UPDATE date_test SET end_date = date( concat( start_date, " ", date_interval));
```

but I get this warning:

> 1292 Truncated incorrect date value: '2012-01-01 - INTERVAL 1 week'

How can I force this date to get evaluated before updating?

Comment: You may have to use date_add. I can't post/verify an answer right now but that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan Leffler said :

> Nearly; there's a crucial difference between the manual page and the question, though. The manual discusses DATE_ADD(date_value, INTERVAL '1' DAY) etc, whereas the question would be having a 'string' value as the second parameter. I fear the question would need a function to convert the string into an INTERVAL type. There doesn't appear to be a 'TO_INTERVAL' function in MySQL.

Here is a function that will take the date as first parameter and the string interval as second parameter.

Simply add the following stored procedure to your database :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_date_add(d DATE, i VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  DECLARE sign CHAR(1);
  DECLARE x INT;

  SET sign = SUBSTRING_INDEX(i, ' ', 1);
  SET x = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(i, ' ', -2), ' ', 1);

  IF sign = '-' THEN
    SET x = -x;
  END IF;

  CASE SUBSTRING_INDEX(i, ' ', -1)
    WHEN 'DAY' THEN SELECT DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL x DAY);
    WHEN 'WEEK' THEN SELECT DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL x WEEK);
    WHEN 'MONTH' THEN SELECT DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL x MONTH);
  END CASE;
END
```

Then you should be able to update your table like this :

```
UPDATE date_test SET end_date = my_date_add(start_date, date_interval);
```

Comment: Thank you HighKick, that worked great.  Except I believe it needs to be a function, not a procedure:


   CREATE FUNCTION my_date_add(d DATE, i VARCHAR(45)) returns date

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You might be right, maybe a function is more appropriate. I don't know if it makes any difference in the end but it does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is :

```
UPDATE date_test SET end_date = DATE_ADD(start_date, date_interval);
```

But I'm not sure that using date_interval as the second parameter will work, tell us if it does.

You will find a lot of useful examples in the MySQL documentation, see [DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function description.

Comment: Nearly; there's a crucial difference between the manual page and the question, though.  The manual discusses `DATE_ADD(date_value, INTERVAL '1' DAY)` etc, whereas the question would be having a 'string' value as the second parameter.  I fear the question would need a function to convert the string into an INTERVAL type.   There doesn't appear to be a 'TO_INTERVAL' function in MySQL.

Comment: Jonathan, I added another answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support values evaluating. So, you cannot use an UPDATE statement directly.

In this case I'd suggest you these ways:

- Write a SELECT...INTO OUTFILE statement that would generate a list of UPDATE statemants and output all this statements into the file, then just run this sript.
- Or write a stored procedure that would open a cursor on `date_test` table, in a loop generate and execute UPDATE statements for each record, one by one, using prepared statements.

Ask, if you have a questions about the solutions.